# Format UDF hard drive as NTFS in Windows 7

Tags: hard-drive, ntfs, format, udf

I have a MyBook hard drive that someone gave to me to format to NTFS. Right now it's UDF and windows treats it like a CD-ROM.

I can't seem to figure out how to format it to be NTFS.

Comment: What is the windows version you are using?

Answer (score 2):

Note do not partion via Windows or 3rd party software like paragon, otherwise you will mess the WD hard drive.

Connect WD HDD to pc, go to open WD smartware and go to the window inside WDsmartware where you will see update software (right bottom corner).

First download the firmware, install, power recycle WD and then reconnect. Download software update, power recycle again. Now you have an NTFS WD. By doing this way you will not harm the drive and it's always reversable to factory setting (e.g. when you want to sell it etc.)

This solution is also valid for WD passport essential SE owners, after following these instructions you will able to disable "VCD" (UDF) so you have unlimited size NTFS.

Comment: I think there's no need to call others "smarties". Just answer the question and let everyone else see if your answer are really better than the others.

Comment: See, it's always a bad idea to call others "smarties", *especially* when you're new to a community. On top of that, Please *don't* use signatures or taglines in your posts. Directly from http://superuser.com/faq.

Answer (score 1):

I first had to reformat the WD usb drive to FAT using a MAC.  Only then was I able to reformat it to NTFS using Windows

Answer (score 1):

After reading [@Son2012's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/127783/format-udf-hard-drive-as-ntfs-in-windows-7/131662#131662), I went to the WD website and updated the installation software and problem solved. It detected the hard drive properly just as it is supposed to.

The link to WD specific website is: http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?level1=1&lang=en

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to work on it via a live boot of Ubuntu and then running gparted. I'm not sure if there's a utility to fix it otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to re-partition it.